# Rails 6 Memory Bloat on Boot

Tags: heroku, memory, memory-management, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

Ever since I upgraded to Rails 6 and started using webpacker my memory consumption on boot (using heroku) has been disastrous.
It peaks at about 1200mb and then goes down afterwards and hangs steadily at approx. 512mb.
I've tried webpacker lazy loading and chunk splitting but to no avail.
Here's the log when I fetch a simple page for the first time after deploying a new build (and restarting dynos):

```
2019-11-29T07:28:35+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=CACHE_REDIS addon=redis-polished-49634 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.11 sample#load-avg-5m=0.11 sample#load-avg-15m=0.135 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664216kB sample#memory-free=12118360kB sample#memory-cached=942820kB sample#memory-redis=313912bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2019-11-29T07:29:14+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED addon=postgresql-metric-77832 sample#current_transaction=79756157 sample#db_size=134809762951bytes sample#tables=38 sample#active-connections=7 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.97867 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.93505 sample#load-avg-1m=0 sample#load-avg-5m=0 sample#load-avg-15m=0 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.083333 sample#tmp-disk-used=2376790016 sample#tmp-disk-available=70602002432 sample#memory-total=4044932kB sample#memory-free=153736kB sample#memory-cached=3543852kB sample#memory-postgres=21172kB
2019-11-29T07:29:49.838066+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/academy/lessons" host=app.makerspro.io request_id=75fae01f-ebe6-49f0-9635-ac92f64430da fwd="77.137.95.95" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-11-29T07:29:53.946177+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=app.makerspro.io request_id=b2d726c1-7742-4556-9302-b3e88f699adb fwd="77.137.95.95" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=207 protocol=https
```

Any ideas how I can get past it? Or at least not time out requests?

Comment: What makes you think Webpacker is the cause of the memory bloat? I would guess that your JS assets are precompiled in production and would be an orthogonal concern to memory bloat on the server side.

Comment: @rossta great question, the only thing that changed in my rails 6 upgrade is the use of webpacker, and Scout pointed at the `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` as the culprit. Do you have any suggestions what else it might be?

Comment: It’d be helpful to have as much info as possible about the errors. Do you have any stacktraces? What info specifically did scout provide? If it’s happening in a Webpacker helper, what is your Webpacker config, etc?

Comment: Here's the logs from my staging env: [link] (http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/15f4e)

Comment: Scout just had a memory bloat pointer that it pointed to the `javascript_pack_tag`

Comment: What's in your public/packs/manifest.json file?

Comment: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/d823d thank you so much or your help!

Comment: Ok, nothing unusual there. What about your `config/webpacker.yml`? Also, do you precompile assets prior to your production deploy?

Comment: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/0aef5 should I cache the manifest? Yes, I precompile otherwise no js works (not sure why)

Comment: Let’s set `compile: false` for production in webpacker.yml

Comment: Yes! That did it! Thank you SO much for your help! Could you put it in a comment so I can accept it as the answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `compile: false` for production in webpacker.yml.

`compile: true` means: [run webpack compilation during the request cycle](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/417542c8ed7d344ecc24b3ae40e303d478ad50d0/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb#L42), something you most likely do not want to do in production since you would instead *pre*compile your assets.